# REMI repository on Centos 7 fails dependency

Tags: centos, rpm, repository

I'm following [these instructions](http://www.servermom.org/how-to-enable-remi-repo-on-centos-7-6-and-5/2790/) to install remi repository (for libsodium) on CentOS 7

```
$> wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
$> sudo rpm -Uvh remi-release-7.rpm
warning: /tmp/remi.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 00f97f56: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        epel-release = 7 is needed by remi-release-7.2-1.el7.remi.noarch
```

How to I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

In think the answer is in the question.

```
    epel-release = 7 is needed by remi-release-7.2-1.el7.remi.noarch
```

So you need to install [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository.

Tips, use the [wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/).

Comment: Wizard rocks! Thanks.